# SQL server 2008 to Postgresql-database transafer

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, postgresql, data-transfer

I have an MS SQL server 2008 database with a 1.3 million rows. I need to transfer databae from one system to another. The other system is using Postgresql instead of MS SQL server. Can any body tell me how can I transfer the data. Will it possible to take the backup of database in MS SQL SERVER other than .BAK extension?

I have tried following :

1) convert the database to MS Acess : But it shows an error "cannot open database . it may not be a database that your application recognizes"

2) show result as text with comma seperator : it shows memmory out of bound exception while saving the file  as text format

3) save as file : that also showing an error.

Comment: Have you taken a look at any of the *many* related questions here or done any prior research?

Comment: yes but i cant find a solution Actually I am in a an urgent situation, can you please point out any answers which can rectify my problem @CraigRinger

Comment: There is no simple one-click solution. You can't just load an MS-SQL database into PostgreSQL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+sql-server+database-migration, https://www.google.com/search?q=migrate+from+sql+server+to+postgresql, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+[sql-server]+convert, etc... and look into ETL tools like Talend Studio, CloverETL, Pentaho Kettle.